# SVG free pixel at position x,y in javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg rect with multiple images inside at different positions, and I need a way to ask if a pixel (x,y) is "free" in the svg, that is the same to me that does not collide with the images, i could ask if the pixel belongs to an image looping one by one but this way seems quite inefficient and i wonder if there is a better way to do this (javascript).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call

```
var element = document.elementFromPoint(x, y);
```

If it returns an element, it's not free, if not, it is. There's more [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint) if you need it.